# Get DataRow from Editable DataGridView in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using editable `DataGridView` where I want to get the row after editing the rows in `DataGridView`.

Here is my `DataGridView` screenshot:

[image]

**My problem is:**

I can Enter as many rows I can. On clicking the "**Register**" button, I am unable to get the Rows from the `DataGridView`.

**What I tried is:**

```
private void enrollmentRegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DataTable data = (DataTable)(childrenDetailsDataGridView.DataSource);
      DataRow[] drArray = new DataRow[data.Rows.Count];
      data.Rows.CopyTo(drArray, 0);
    }
```

**What I want is:**

I should be able to get the `DataRow` entered dynamically in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Did you set `DataSource` of the grid to a `DataTable`? Do you mean you need to get only new rows added after loading data?

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: **-** Why you defined all properties of `Child` as string? **-** Where is definition of `Child` class? **-** The current answer has some issues. Also there is better ways to get values and fill a typed list. **-** If you like to receive a better answer, edit your question. Now question and answer are not related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from DataGridView make your code like that.
 And then you can take rows from DataTable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting data from DataGridView
        DataTable myDt = new DataTable();
        myDt = GetDTfromDGV(dataGridView1);
    }
private DataTable GetDTfromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        // Macking our DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6]
            {
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[0].Name, typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[1].Name, typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[2].Name, typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[3].Name, typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[4].Name, typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[5].Name, typeof(int))
            });
        // Getting data
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgv.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int col = 0; col < dgv.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                dr[col] = dgvRow.Cells[col].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : dgvRow.Cells[col].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        // removing empty rows
        for (int row = dt.Rows.Count - 1; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[row][col] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == true)
            {
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you need to return List

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Getting data from DataGridView
    var list = GetDTfromDGV(dataGridView1);
}

private dynamic GetDTfromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    .....
    .....

    var list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
List<Child> childrenList = new List<Child>();


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in childrenDetailsDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                bool IsRowEmpty = true;
                    if (row.Cells.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Child child = new Child();
                        if (row.Cells["Childname"].Value !=null)
                        {
                            IsRowEmpty = false;
                            child.Childname = row.Cells["Childname"].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        if (row.Cells["Gender"].Value != null)
                        {
                            child.Gender = row.Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        if (row.Cells["Age"].Value != null)
                        {
                            child.Age = row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        if (row.Cells["Star"].Value != null)
                        {
                            child.Star = row.Cells["Star"].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        if (row.Cells["Occupation"].Value != null)
                        {
                            child.Occupation = row.Cells["Occupation"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        if (!IsRowEmpty)
                        {
                            childrenList.Add(child);
                        }

                    }
            }
```

It's very simple.